# Java 9 Webstart loads jar file multiple times

Tags: java, caching, java-web-start, jnlp, java-9

since jre 9.0.4 we are dealing with a problem when starting our swing application with webstart.
It seems that the jar file, containing the main class, is loaded very often from the server. Probably everytime the application loads a resource, which is included in the jar file. Because the size of the jar file is 6Mb, the app is very slow.
The last modified timestamp is always the same and there is no need to update the jar every time. Using versioning in the jnlp file also didn't helped.

Console output:

> network: Verbindung von http://myurl.net/application.jar mit Proxy=DIRECT wird hergestellt
>   network: Verbindung von http://myurl.net/application.jar mit Proxy=DIRECT wird hergestellt
>   network: Verbindung von http://myurl.net/application.jar mit Proxy=DIRECT wird hergestellt
>   network: Verbindung von http://myurl.net/application.jar mit Proxy=DIRECT wird hergestellt
>   network: Verbindung von http://myurl.net/application.jar mit Proxy=DIRECT wird hergestellt
>   network: Verbindung von http://myurl.net/application.jar mit Proxy=DIRECT wird hergestellt
>   network: Verbindung von http://myurl.net/application.jar mit Proxy=DIRECT wird hergestellt
>   network: Verbindung von http://myurl.net/application.jar mit Proxy=DIRECT wird hergestellt

With jre8 the problem is not present.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Danny

Comment: is it really being fully loaded every time? Or is it just attempting to load it several times? "Verbindung wird hergestellt" only means it is establishing the connection...

Comment: The network traffic is very high all the time the application is frozen and the java cache folder contains about 100MB. So i guess its loaded fully just to extract or access the resource files inside the jar

Comment: Did you find where the problem was? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: unfortunatly not